# Android App starting slow - dex2oat Zip is absent. Canceled - Gradle 2.10

Tags: android, gradle, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services, android-instant-run

I wrote an Android App which worked fine so far.
Then I added the features for Google Cloud Messaging (GCM). I used the demo project from Google which seems to have added analytics and app indexing etc.

Now starting the app works as intended but takes a lot of time. The log shows many messages like this:

```
I/dex2oat: ----------------------------------------------------
I/dex2oat: <SS>: S T A R T I N G . . .
I/dex2oat: <SS>: Zip is absent. Canceled.
I/dex2oat: /system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=div --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --dex-file=/data/data/world.b2g.b2gether/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.android.gms-play-services-measurement-8.4.0_d76b40d326ea93493481fa158b18846c1c4627dd-classes.dex --oat-fd=29 --art-fd=-1 --oat-location=/data/data/world.b2g.b2gether/cache/slice-com.google.android.gms-play-services-measurement-8.4.0_d76b40d326ea93493481fa158b18846c1c4627dd-classes.dex --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m
I/dex2oat: dex2oat took 288.616ms (threads: 4)
I/dex2oat: ----------------------------------------------------
I/dex2oat: <SS>: S T A R T I N G . . .
I/dex2oat: <SS>: Zip is absent. Canceled.
I/dex2oat: /system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=div --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --dex-file=/data/data/world.b2g.b2gether/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.android.gms-play-services-maps-8.4.0_36e4d7c4ee371ae72ff4fba4383d7535cc7f3d3a-classes.dex --oat-fd=29 --art-fd=-1 --oat-location=/data/data/world.b2g.b2gether/cache/slice-com.google.android.gms-play-services-maps-8.4.0_36e4d7c4ee371ae72ff4fba4383d7535cc7f3d3a-classes.dex --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m
I/dex2oat: dex2oat took 321.095ms (threads: 4)
I/dex2oat: ----------------------------------------------------
I/dex2oat: <SS>: S T A R T I N G . . .
I/dex2oat: <SS>: Zip is absent. Canceled.
I/dex2oat: /system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=div --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --dex-file=/data/data/world.b2g.b2gether/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.android.gms-play-services-location-8.4.0_298f1e5056d6eea423c13052ef0c9136963ce27b-classes.dex --oat-fd=29 --art-fd=-1 --oat-location=/data/data/world.b2g.b2gether/cache/slice-com.google.android.gms-play-services-location-8.4.0_298f1e5056d6eea423c13052ef0c9136963ce27b-classes.dex --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m
I/dex2oat: dex2oat took 298.720ms (threads: 4)
I/dex2oat: ----------------------------------------------------
...
```

It appears as if some packages are missing.
Since I don't need any of these features (except for maps and GCM) I deactivated the options for Analytics, Authentication... in Android Studio . Yet, these messages still appear.

Could this be because I apply the services in the build.gradle file?

```
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/greendao-2.1.0.jar')
    compile project(':volley')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

In the app gradle config I also wrote

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0'
    }
}
```

**-------------------------- EDIT : --------------------------**

**Turns out it seems to be gradle's fault**

I traced the problem a bit back to the point when I updated to the new Android Studio. At one point I had to switch from **Gradle 2.8** to **Gradle 2.10**. If I change it to Gradle 2.8 this problem is gone. Unfortunately Android Studio tells me I have to update to 2.10 now.

*So what can I do?*

**----------------------- EDIT 07.June.2016 : -----------------------**

It looks like with the new update to Android Studio 2.1.2 this bug is fixed (or at least I don't see this message any more)

Comment: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'` It's almost never a good idea to include the entire play services library, why do you do it? Besides you already seem to include the partial libraries that you need

Comment: It was included that way in the example project from Google. I might check that again. So should I remove that from the classpath aswell in the gradle dependencies? classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-beta6'

Comment: You need the reference in the classpath as well as the `apply plugin`, but you do not need the `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'`, also why did you manually edit the generated json file?

Comment: I edited it because it already had all the other services (ads, analytics, ...) included. This seemed to be wrong.

Comment: Note that GCM has status 2 and all the others have status 1, I don't think you're supposed to edit that file. I'm not 100% sure though

Comment: Yea, I kept it at status 2. Not sure what that means though.

Comment: @TobiasReich so did you resolve your problem and if so - how?

Comment: @TobiasReich where do you change the gradle version?

Comment: No, I couldn't solve the problem. 
When I opened the project in Android Studio it told me to change. Still I did in File-> Project Structure-> Project-> Gradle Version: 2.10

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally I found the answer. The problem was really Gradle.
But not the new version itself. Much more the instand build.

**What I learned:**

Problem seems to be that with the enabled **Instant Run** some "slices" for frameworks can't be found. This also affects the phone when running the app independently from the compiler (e.g. starting if via the App Drawer).
It appears as if the already compiled libraries have to be searched/linked/compiled again.
The reason this happens only with Gradle 2.10 or higher was not the version itself but merely that Gradle 2.8 doesn't support the new feature.

**The Solution:**

For now the best work around was to deactivate this funcionality in:

*Settings/Build, Execution, Deployment/Instant Run -> Enable Instant Run to hot swap code*

*>> EDIT:
Still the update to Android Studio 2.1 doesn't seem to fix this problem to me.*

[image]

Comment: Instant Run with GCM and PS made my apps' startup times very slow too. :/

Comment: Maybe you might take a look at the log and see if you get the same problems with dex2oat as I did. You won't find it in the "selected application" though so take a look at the correct filter.

Comment: No. In my case it hangs on a huge line starting like `I/InstantRun: Incremental dex path is /...` No special log lines in the system.

Comment: Hm, sorry, this error is none I have. Guess I can't help you with this.

Comment: This fixed the slow app startup but why is this happening? so many unknowns with Android Studio

Comment: For me it only happen for the first run, where the OS would generate ~20MB of data in app cache dir. It still occurs in AS 2.2. Preview 2, guess Google doesn't consider it a problem or at least not a high-priority one.

Comment: I wasted so much time thinking there was a problem with my app causing slow startup, thank you

Answer (score -1):

I also run into this problem.
My app's loading speed is too slow.
I checked the logcat below.
I/dex2oat: dex2oat took 288.616ms 
After I unchecked the option box that the writer mentioned the problem has solved.